# How to create a shared component that takes in an array and display checkboxes in React?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-component

I am having trouble creating a shared component so I can reuse it somewhere else if needed. My shared component would take in props(array of lets say names) and displays a group of checkboxes with the names to the right on each one. How would I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

you pass your props to your component like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import Checkboxes from "./Checkboxes"

const data = [ "name 1", "name 2", "name3"]
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Checkboxes data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And on your component you map through that array, like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Checkboxes = (props) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (item) => {
    if (selected.includes(item)) {
      const newSelected = [...selected];
      newSelected.splice(selected.indexOf(item), 1);
      return setSelected(newSelected);
    }
    const newSelected = [...selected];
    newSelected.push(item);
    return setSelected(newSelected);
  };

  return (
    <form>
      {props.data.map((item) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={Math.random()}>
            <label>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={selected.includes(item) ? true : false}
                onChange={() => handleChange(item)}
                name={item}
                value={item}
              />
              {item}
            </label>
            <br />
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </form>
  );
};

export default Checkboxes;
```

Here is the [exemple sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-haze-pdlg8?file=/src/Checkboxes.js:0-395)

Comment: To give a html element an id is not a good idea, you will create invalid html this way, instead you can do `<label><input><label>` and leave out the id. This is not a very useful react component because it has uncontrolled inputs and no component is notified when a change happens. Also your sandbox is broken.

Comment: Hi, truly appreciate the feedback, helped me learn a lot. It's funny how a simple needs such an elaboration to be done the right way. Here is the sandbox corrected, I'd appreciate your feedback! https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-haze-pdlg8?file=/src/Checkboxes.js

Comment: That will work, +1. I have added a hidden snippet in my answer that will maintain a list of values and a list of selected values (same as your example) but with the ability to pass a template for the list and item as well as item being a pure component and won't re render if it doesn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a constant NAMES defined:

```
const NAMES = ["one" , "two", "three"];
```

your render method of React component would look like this:

```
return (
    <div>
       {NAMES.map(el => (
           <div key={el} >
                <input type="checkbox" name={el} value={el}/>
                <label htmlFor={el}> {el}</label>
            </div>
       ))}    
    </div>
)
```

Explanation:

NAMES is an array. By mapping over this array, you are returning an array of JSX elements (those 4 lines starting with <div ... ). Each of this element is your checkbox. So by using map function, you save code and you create as much elements as you need, algoritmically.

Each element of the array has to have unique key prop. Also the name of the checkbox is displayed in the label tag.

Comment: When the checkbox changes value how do you update the names or notify anything that it has been changed? React renders data and notifies when data needs to change but your solution does not have that so it's not a very useful component.

Comment: This is an uncontrolled component. To create a controlled one, just add checked and onChange properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const Item = React.memo(function Item({
  label,
  id,
  checked,
  onChange,
}) {
  return (
    <li>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={() => onChange(id, !checked)}
        />
        {label}
      </label>
    </li>
  );
});
const ItemList = React.memo(function ItemList({
  items,
  onChange,
  Item,
}) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(({ id, label, checked }) => (
        <Item
          key={id}
          id={id}
          label={label}
          checked={checked}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
});
const CheckBoxList = React.memo(function CheckBoxList({
  items,
  onChange,
  List = ItemList,
  ListItem = Item,
}) {
  return (
    <List
      items={items}
      onChange={onChange}
      Item={ListItem}
    />
  );
});
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, label: 'item 1', checked: false },
    { id: 2, label: 'item 2', checked: false },
  ]);
  const onChange = React.useCallback(
    (id, checked) =>
      setData((data) =>
        data.map((item) =>
          item.id === id ? { ...item, checked } : item
        )
      ),
    []
  );
  return <CheckBoxList items={data} onChange={onChange} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here is another way of doing it:

```js
const Item = React.memo(function Item({
  value,
  onChange,
  checked,
}) {
  return (
    <li>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={() => onChange(value, !checked)}
        />
        {value}
      </label>
    </li>
  );
});
const createItemContainer = (Component = Item) => ({
  value,
  onChange,
  selected,
}) => (
  <Component
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    checked={selected.includes(value)}
  />
);

const ItemList = React.memo(function ItemList({
  values,
  onChange,
  Item,
  selected,
}) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {values.map((value) => (
        <Item
          key={value}
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          selected={selected}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
});
const DefaultItem = createItemContainer();
const CheckBoxList = React.memo(function CheckBoxList({
  values,
  onChange,
  selected,
  List = ItemList,
  ListItem = DefaultItem,
}) {
  return (
    <List
      values={values}
      onChange={onChange}
      Item={ListItem}
      selected={selected}
    />
  );
});
const App = () => {
  const data = React.useMemo(() => ['A', 'B', 'C'], []);
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
  const onChange = React.useCallback(
    (item, checked) =>
      setSelected((selected) =>
        checked
          ? selected.concat(item)
          : selected.filter((s) => s !== item)
      ),
    []
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <CheckBoxList
          values={data}
          onChange={onChange}
          selected={selected}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>Items selected</h4>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(selected)}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using function:

```
export default function CheckboxComponent({ arr }) {
  return (
    <>
      <p>{arr}</p>
      {arr.map((item) => (
        <div key={item}>
          <input type="checkbox" name={item} value={item} />
          <label htmlFor={item}>{item}</label>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

And to call your component, just import and you'll be able to use it normally:

```
import CheckboxComponent from "./components/checkbox-component";

export default function App() {   
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CheckboxComponent arr={["Banana", "Apple"]} />
      <CheckboxComponent arr={["Pineapple", "Watermelon"]} />
      <CheckboxComponent arr={["Blueberry", "Strawberry"]} />
    </div>   
  ); 
}
```

Here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/including-values-on-checkbox-vb30v?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Not a very useful component, it has no onChange handler and no way of notifying it's consumer something has changed

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your message. Why would it need to notify the checkbox change? Do you mean when its clicked?

Comment: You created an [uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) it only renders data but can't indicate that data has changed when user checks or unchecks a checkbox.